# Cannot understand SerializerRelated fields (CustomSlugRelatedField)

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I had written a CustomSlugRelatedField class a long time back. I cannot remember and figure out what purpose it solved earlier, as both the SlugRelatedField and my CustomSlugRelatedField have the same functionality

```
class CustomSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        query_field = kwargs.pop('query_field', None)
        
        super(CustomSlugRelatedField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if query_field:
            self.query_field = query_field
        else:
            self.query_field = self.slug_field
    
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(**{self.query_field: data})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', query_field=self.query_field, value=smart_text(data))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing this code with [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py), I think here you are passing an additional field name `query_field`, along with the `slug_field`, which can be used to get the object from the queryset. The usage might be like this:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSeirlaizer):
     some_field = CustomSlugRelatedField(query_field='some_field', slug_field="something_else")
```

Feels redundant though, because you already have `slug_field` to do the same thing for you.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it would help if you would want to show a different field but query on basis of a different field